# Good Android based IDE for developing Android apps

Tags: android, ide

OK, there is at least one, arguably more, PC based IDE for developing Android apps.

But now that Android based tablets are becoming common, what's a good IDE for developing Android apps - in Android?

---

Edit: I'd be more than happy to use Eclipse if it runs in Android ... or Netbeans, although that seems less likely?

Reason for the question is that I just acquired an Android slate & Want it to eat its own dog food.

Comment: Any reasonst against using the Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: +1 No reason at all - if it will run in Android - will it?

Comment: Interesting, though I wonder if that's really performant when developing with a full-fledged IDE on a slate. Let us know the outcome.

Comment: +1 Matthias. I want to sell customers slate based apps, so I will be carrying a slate to demo them. So, why not try slate based development?  (it might take a while, though, with the virtual keyword ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read about this on some news site, so i don't have any experience using it. It is surely not a full-fledged IDE, but at least you could write apps for the android on the android.

[Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

[PHPForAndroid](http://www.phpforandroid.net/)

Answer (score 5):

There are no Android development tools for Android made yet - the SDK is for Linux/Mac/Windows. There are no IDEs too that I know.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse plug-in is by far the best.  Not really too many others.  Certainly none at the moment (except simple text editors) actually on Android.

Comment: Eclipse might be the best free option, but IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate Edition) is more stable and seems to have less bugs (i.e. regarding project refresh, indicating build errors where there are none, etc.) than Eclipse, it's just not free. Worked with both, felt less pain with IDEA ;)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is the 'official' IDE for developing Android applications, partly because Google themselves wrote the Android plugins and use it to develop their own apps. So of course it's well supported, stable, and includes excellent support for the emulator, building and debugging tools

I'd suggest you use it. It's really good!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the app ["Bright MIDE"](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.bright_side.brightmide) (or free read only version ["Bright MIDE Read Only"](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.bright_side.brightmide_readonly)) on the Android Market. I has a computer-like keyboard and uses the Eclipse keyboard shortcuts. You can edit and build apps with it - almost like in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take AIDE for a spin:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aide.ui

It has syntax highlighting, code completion and supports the full edit-compile-run cycle for developing Android Apps on Android devices.

Also it is compatible with the Eclipse project format.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Illumination Software Creator. http://radicalbreeze.com/

Comment: +! a bit simplistic, but thanks

Comment: Chrome throws up a malware warning for this site. I'm guessing its been abandoned.